# Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment' in Ionic projec

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When running `ng-serve` in my ionic project, I get the below error,

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.service.ts:7:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment'.
>
> 7 import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

I am using Angular 7 and Ionic 4, And since i am new to Ionic. Can anyone help me out

I have tried changing  `'environments/environment' by 'src/environments/environment'` , running `npm run env` , running `import { environment } from '../environments/environment';` and nothing worked. Thank you

My **environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseApi: 'http://api.aladhan.com/v1/'
};
```

My **environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseApi: 'http://api.aladhan.com/v1/'
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but `ionic serve` is the command to use in an Ionic app. Have you tried that instead of `ng serve`? Maybe it loads the environment different? IDK, just an idea.

Comment: show your `environment` code

Comment: @haron68 environment codes added

Comment: @Narm Still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `import {environment} from ‘./src/environments/environment’;` or `import {environment} from ‘environments/environment’;`

Answer (score 1):

Just look for tsconfig.json file

You can add Path definition for this kindo folders.. they usually start with @

And ends with '/*' and ad a parameter path takes an array like for example

`"compilerOptions": { "paths": { "@environments/*": ["environments/*"], ...`

for extra "resolveJsonModule": true, parameter sometimes usefull

regards.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, inside the angular src folder, create  enviroments folder and add environment.ts file. In that file, paste the following`export const environment = {}`now you can install angular fire using `ng add @angular/fire`